# c++ BOF vulnerability in this code please some one explain

Tags: c++

what is the vulnerabilty in this code please some one explain me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int arc, char* argv[])
{
    char buff[50];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    printf("You are string: %s", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: imagine that you invoked the program with an argument longer than 49 characters. What happens?

Comment: `strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);` should also read `strcpy(buff, argv[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1]` may not exist, or it could be longer than 50 chars => problem.
Solution: Check if `argc >=2` and `strlen(argv[1])<50`

Otherwise, your program has undefined behaviour,
means it can do something strange and unexpected.
Additionally, malicious humans maybe can inject own code

Comment: The solution is already in the answer. Do you know how to make an if condition?